# dotnet core does AuthenticationHandler been invoked on Allowanonymous routes?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, bearer-token

My question is does `AuthenticationHandler` or a derived `AuthenticationHandler` is been invoked on `AllowAnonymous` routes?

In our application we use custom authentication flows for the applications. All of those flows include default `Bearer` Authentication as our custom authentication handler that extends on `JwtBearerHandler` (Well at least this is a plan for the implementation)

```
public class ApplicationAuthenticationHandler : JwtBearerHandler
```

Before digging deeper into this I wanted to understand if these handlers will be invoked on  `AllowAnonymous` routes or I would have to check for those routes manually or perhaps register Authentication in some custom way for these handlers not to be triggered on those routes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, as long as you use `UseAuthentication` default or custom authentication handlers will be triggered even on AllowAnonymous. So you you would have to handle your allow anonyms routes in side of your custom authentication handler if you need to authentication user in any other way other than default handlers.